# What is the difference between !=null check and null safe operator in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying to conditionally show a GameObject in Unity by using a public variable. If the variable is set in the component window, then I should hide the gameObject to activate it in the future. If not set, then I should do nothing. I had this but it gave me a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
public GameObject optionalGO; //May be set from GUI

void Start(){
    optionalGO?.SetActive(false); //Gives error
}
```

Then I changed the line giving an error to this, and it worked fine:

```
if(optionalGO!= null) optionalGO.SetActive(false);
```

I don't understand the difference, there is nothing otherwordly about the rest of the script or the context. Why are these lines not equivalent?

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The first one checks whether `ReferenceEquals`. _Most articles say they are equivalent, but they assume you aren't working with "insane" code (i.e. Unity)._

Comment: Comparing to `null` in Unity has special meaning - because `GameObject` type has it's own `==` operator overload. Operator-independent null check can be done via `if (X is null) ...`.

Comment: In short: Never use a `null` check or nullable for anything deriving from `UnityEngine.Object` .. it sometimes behaves unexpected. Rather use `if(optionalGO) optionalGO.SetActive(false);`